# Trying to wrap a function around my tibble-creating code

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

Code without the function wrap does what is required, but returns NULL when I wrap a function around it

Following the advice that any code copied twice should be turned into a function, I tried to make a function out of the tibbles that I frequently generate in my program.

But when I go to put it in a function, NULL is returned

```
# This works
for.gas <- tibble(Year = (start-1):(start+h-1))
for(i in countries){
  test.df           <- tibble(Year = (start-1):(start+h-1),
                              n    = NA
  )
  colnames(test.df) <- c("Year", paste(i))
  for.gas           <- left_join(for.gas, test.df)
}

# This doesn't
create.df <- function(df_name){
df_name <- tibble(Year = (start-1):(start+h-1))
for(i in countries){
  test.df           <- tibble(Year = (start-1):(start+h-1),
                              n    = NA
  )
  colnames(test.df) <- c("Year", paste(i))
  df_name           <- left_join(df_name, test.df)
}
}

# Expected results
# A tibble: 31 x 5
    Year Argentina Belgium Brazil Canada
   <int> <lgl>     <lgl>   <lgl>  <lgl> 
 1  2017 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 2  2018 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 3  2019 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 4  2020 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 5  2021 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 6  2022 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 7  2023 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 8  2024 NA        NA      NA     NA    
 9  2025 NA        NA      NA     NA    
10  2026 NA        NA      NA     NA    
# ... with 21 more rows
```

All help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the assignment to 'df_name' happened but it is not `return`ed

```
create.df <- function(df_name){
df_name <- tibble(Year = (start-1):(start+h-1))
for(i in countries){
  test.df           <- tibble(Year = (start-1):(start+h-1),
                              n    = NA
  )
     colnames(test.df) <- c("Year", paste(i))
     df_name           <- left_join(df_name, test.df)
     # assignment happened within the for loop
  }
 df_name  # note this step
 # or explicitly state to return (though not needed)
 # return(df_name) 
}

create.df(for.gas)
```

Comment: That was a lightning fast reply! I had to sleep and go to work before thanking you for the help!